# Modular symbols associated to Rankin Selberg convolutions and the symmetric square

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, l-functions, iwasawa-theory

I'm interested in understanding how one may associate modular symbols to the L-functions and $p$-adic L-functions associated to the Rankin Selberg convolution of two modular forms/ elliptic curves and the symmetric square of a modular form/elliptic curves. Looking through the literature I see that the $\operatorname{GL}_{n-1}\times \operatorname{GL}_n$ case has been treated in general, for instance "Modular symbols for reductive groups and p-adic Rankin-Selberg convolutions over number fields"-Januszewski ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1625)/[publisher link](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crll.2011.2011.issue-653/crelle.2011.018/crelle.2011.018.xml)) and "Relative modular symbols and $p$-adic Rankin-Selberg convolutions"-Schmidt ([behind paywall](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01232425)).

Is there a reference for the theory of modular symbols in the $\operatorname{GL}_{2}\times \operatorname{GL}_2$ and $\operatorname{Sym}^2$ cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think there is a reference for this theory, because as far as I know no such theory exists. I have spent a substantial portion of my career studying the arithmetic of the special values of the $GL_2 \times GL_2$ Rankin--Selberg L-function, and I am not aware of a theory of modular symbols in this setting.

Comment: I understand that there are technicalities involved, but would it be possible to state what it makes the $\operatorname{GL}_2\times \operatorname{GL}_3$ tractable and the $\operatorname{GL}_2\times \operatorname{GL}_2$ case out of reach?

Comment: The group $G = GL_3 \times GL_2$ has a reductive subgroup $H$, namely the copy of $GL_2$ embedded via $g \mapsto (g \oplus 1, g)$, such that $H$ has an open orbit on the Borel flag variety of $G$ with trivial stabiliser. No such subgroup exists in $GL_2 \times GL_2$.